# PowerShell: strange handling of exception

Tags: powershell, exception, try-catch

I am learning PowerShell these days and have come across some odd behavior. After running the following code, whose only purpose is to understand exception handling:

```
try

{

throw [System.IO.FileNotFoundException]::new("Thrown a file not found exception")

}

catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException]

{

    Write-Output "Entered catch"

}
```

I get that "Entered catch" is shown onscreen. Why does this happen, if according to online documentation System.IO.FileNotFoundException does not have System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException in its line of inheritance? In other words, I was expecting the exception not to be caught and the corresponding exception error message to be seen onscreen instead.

Comment: But if I am throwing a System.IO.FileNotFoundException then it is required that its BaseType (or any other BaseType up in the line of inheritance) be of type System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException, which is not the case. In other words, it is not enough if the two of them are children/grandchildren of type SystemException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The behavior, present up to at least PowerShell Core 7.2.0-rc.1 (current as of this writing), is **arguably a *bug***.

  - As you state, the [`System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException) exception type is *not* a base class of [`System.IO.FileNotFoundException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileNotFoundException), and therefore shouldn't trigger the `catch` block.
  - The problem has been reported in [GitHub issue #16392](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16392)
- That said, catching `System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException` is virtually pointless, as it is the (conceptually speaking) *abstract* base class for *specific* PowerShell exception types such as, say, [`System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException).<sup>[1]</sup>

---

**In practice, `catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException]` seems to behave like an *unqualified* [`catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally), i.e. it catches *any* exception** (not caught by another, more specific, typed `catch` block, if present).

If, at a high level, you need to distinguish between exception types derived from `System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException` vs. those that aren't, you can use an unqualified `catch` block in which you can use `-is`, the [type(-inheritance) / interface test operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Operators):

```sh
try
{
  throw [System.IO.FileNotFoundException]::new("Thrown a file not found exception")
}
catch {

  $isPSException = $_.Exception -is [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException]

  "Exception is RuntimeException-derived: $isPSException"
}
```

---

<sup>[1] A rare example of where `System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException` is used *directly* is the statement-terminating error triggered by `1 / 0`</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your updates!!! As you point out, the code I wrote was pointless and that was on purpose: I just wanted to understand the behavior of PowerShell's Exception handling and was getting extremely confused by this behavior I found. I am glad to hear that it is a bug and that an official report has been created.